# How to preload local fonts using next.js

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, next.js, styled-components

I'm using next.js.

I want to load the fonts before the content is painted on the screen.
I tried to add them in the `Head` component in `_.document` file with `rel="preload"`

```
<link
        rel="preload"
        href="/public/fonts/Mulish-ExtraBold.ttf"
        as="font"
        type="font/ttf"
        crossOrigin="anonymous"
      ></link>
```

I added a `public` directory in the root and a font directory inside of it and then as a `href` the link tag like this as you can see above`href="/public/fonts/Mulish-ExtraBold.ttf"` as you see.

```
href="/public/fonts/Mulish-ExtraBold.ttf"
```

But it doesn't seem to work as expected

here is `_.document.tsx` file

```
import Document, { Head, Html, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import { ServerStyleSheet } from "styled-components";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link
            rel="preload"
            href="/public/fonts/Mulish-ExtraBold.ttf"
            as="font"
            type="font/ttf"
            crossOrigin="anonymous"
          ></link>
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
```

What am i missing?

Comment: What is not working as expected? What behaviour are you seeing? By the way, the file should be named `_document.tsx` (without the extra dot).

Comment: It is not preloading the font, i changed the name and still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `/public` that will fix your issue